# WHERE IN (...) OR IN (...) clause?

Tags: sql-server, where-clause

What I am trying to do is pull data back if an ID exists in two different tables, so for instance:

```
select details from myTable
where myTable.id in (select id from tbl1) or myTable.id in (select id from tbl2)
```

So far I have not had any luck. Am I doing this correctly? If not, could you guys suggest methods by which I could get the desired outcome?

The issue(s) that I am having is that the query hangs and I am unsure if that is due to a malformed query or some other reason that I am not thinking of.

Comment: What is the problem you are having? Does the query not return data you think it should, or is it hanging while executing, or something else?

Comment: If it needs to exist in both, did you think about using AND instead of OR? If something else, maybe you could show us what you expected (what is the sample data and desired outcome), or what "not had any luck" means.

Comment: @AaronBertrand No, the ID in question only needs to exist in either tbl1 or tbl2 so my 'OR' is correct in that instance. The issue(s) that I am having is that the query hangs and I am unsure if that is due to a malformed query or some other reason that I am not thinking of.

Comment: No, a malformed query would return an error immediately. A query typically "hangs" either (a) because it is blocked or (b) because it is using an extremely inefficient execution plan. Have you checked for blocking? Are there indexes on any of the tables? What are they? How many rows in each table? What does an estimated execution plan tell you it's going to try to do?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've accepted the answer below, but there were missing indexes on the tbls I was hitting. Fixed those too thanks to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using a UNION:

```
SELECT details 
FROM dbo.myTable
WHERE 
    myTable.id IN (SELECT id FROM dbo.tbl1
                   UNION
                   SELECT id FROM dbo.tbl2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check if it exists in both tables, you could do something like:

```
SELECT details
FROM dbo.myTable A
WHERE EXISTS (  SELECT 1
                FROM dbo.tbl1 B
                INNER JOIN dbo.tbl2 C
                   ON B.ID = C.ID
                WHERE A.ID = B.ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

This would return data from myTable if the id exists in *either* of tbl1 or tbl2:

```
SELECT details
 from myTable mt
 where exists (select id from tbl1 where id = mt.id)
  or exists (select id from tbl2 where id = mt.id)
```

For large tables, this will perform better than union-based queries (assuming suitable indexing) as you are just checking for existance, and not retrieving data from those other tables.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do it with only joins, and no subqueries:

```
SELECT details FROM myTable
LEFT JOIN tbl1 ON tbl1.id = myTable.id
LEFT JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.id = myTable.id
WHERE tbl1.id IS NOT NULL OR tbl2.id IS NOT NULL
```

If this still hangs or takes a long time, it is possible that there is not an index on one of these `id` columns. Though, `id` is usually a primary key which is automatically indexed, so this is unlikely.

I should add that if any of these `id` columns could be duplicated, i.e. more than one row in `tbl1` with the same `id`, then this will result in duplicate copies of `details`. Again, I am assuming that all the `id` columns are primary keys, so this would not be a concern.